# How to select element with a colon in its className?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I fix a selector with slash colon in class name?

Here is my sample Javascript:

```js
$('.scroll-spy\:indigo-tab').addClass("active");
```

But that doesn't add the `active` class.

This is my css:

```css
.scroll-spy\:blue-tab.active {
  background: var(--color-blue);
  border: solid 2px var(--color-blue);
}
```

Comment: Is the colon as a part of the class name something you can't change? As you can see, this makes writing code around it more complicated. I'd recommend avoiding colons in class names.

Comment: What's the html?  Does your css work if you remove the .active part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the backslash as well. For this reason I recommend you don't use colons (`:`) in the `class` attribute on your HTML, it makes this more complicated than it needs to be.

```js
// Escape the slash AND escape the colon
// '\\' + '\:'
$('.scroll-spy\\\:blue-tab').addClass('active');
```

```css
.scroll-spy\:blue-tab.active {
  background: cyan;
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll-spy:blue-tab">Element</div>
```