# Trigger Pop Up Message whenever a button is click by using Class Name

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, popup

I would like to trigger a pop up message whenever people click on a button.

My button is of

```
<button _ngcontent-c15="" class="send mat-icon-button ng-star-inserted" mat-icon-button="" disabled=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><mat-icon _ngcontent-c15="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">cloud_upload</mat-icon></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

And my pop up javascript is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    
window.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        2000 
    )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
    </script>
```

How can I assign that button class to the pop up to make it appear every time people click on the button?

I have tried this method but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('send:after');

for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
 elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
       

     
 }, false);
}
    



document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
    </script>
```

Hopefully can get some guidance on this. Thank You

Comment: there are many problems. first, CSS class names cannot contain  `:`

Comment: @pierpy Noted with thanks. The answer below did suggest me to add \\ to it.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: In the answers below, I assume that by "pop up" you mean an alert.*

#### One button

If you have **only one button** with the class `class="send:after"` the JavaScript code could look like this.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('send:after')[0].addEventListener("click", myPopupFunction);

function myPopupFunction() {
  alert('Hey, you clicked on my button!')
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="myBtn" value="Search">
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also use `querySelector` method to get the button element. Note that in this case, we need to add `\\` to the class selector in order to escape the colon in the class name - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599985/11875147). As you can see, generally speaking, using **colon in a class name is not a good idea**. The code with `querySelector` could look like this.

```js
document.querySelector('.send\\:after').addEventListener("click", myPopupFunction)
function myPopupFunction() {
  alert('Hey, you clicked on my button!')
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="myBtn" value="Search">
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also define the pop up directly in HTML, e.g.:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="alert('Hey, you clicked on my button!')">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Multiple buttons

If you have **multiple buttons** with the class `class="send:after"` the JavaScript code could look like this.

```js
var all_button_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('send:after')

for(var i = 0; i < all_button_elements.length; i++) {
  all_button_elements[i].addEventListener("click", myPopupFunction)
}

function myPopupFunction() {
  alert('Hey, you clicked on my button!')
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="myBtn" value="Search">
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="myBtn2" value="Search2">
    <input type="button" class="send:after" id="myBtn3" value="Search3">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but unfortunately it still couldn't initiate pop up after clicking the button. May I know is there any other methods to do it?

Comment: Does the code not work only in your appliaction or do the snippets also not work for you? The snippets here on Stack Overflow work for me, so if they do not work for you, it may be possible that your browser blocks the pop-ups.

Comment: I have tried your solution here on Stack Overflow also working fine. I think it is just not working in my application. For your information, the class="send:after" was assign to a button in a POS plugin, may be the document.getElementsByClassName('send:after') was not linking to that button

Comment: You can try renaming the class or you can try referencing the button using its id (`document.getElementById("myBtn")`) and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Jakub, the button does not have an ID and for now I cant find its file location. May I know is it possible to add an ID to it using css or any other methods?

Comment: Please add the HTML code which defines the button to your question. Without the code, it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I have edited my question with HTML code defining the button. Thank You